# Present Continuous+never for emotional tone

Tags: tense, adverbs, present-tense, present-continuous

As we know Present Continuous is used with *always / constantly* to express some emotional nuance (often negative).
e.g. My sister is always borrowing my clothes without asking!
Can we similarly use *never*
e.g. He is never telling the truth.

Comment: Idiomatically speaking, you definitely *can't* combine ***never*** with the continuous participle the same as ***always***. If there's a *reason* for this (as opposed to just *established idiomatic usage*), maybe it's to do with the fact that continuous actions require *time* during which to happen, which ***never*** explicitly denies exists for the cited action.

Comment: But we can use _never_ with states that _are_ continuing - "He's never at home when I call" - "You're never in a good mood early in the morning."

Answer (score 1):

No, the usage of *[ "always" + continuous ]* to express annoyance about a regularly occurring event is a fixed structure, and doesn't allow any other adverbs of frequency to be used in the place of "always" and keep that function.

The sentence "*He's never telling the truth*" is good grammar, but is just a neutral statement with no nuance of negativity. It could mean many things in the right context -- including expressing a regularly occurring event -- but none of them add the nuance of annoyance:

> He files a complaint every week or so, but he's never telling the truth.

In this case, "*he's never telling the truth*" roughly means *in each case, it turns out that he's not telling the truth*. While that situation may or not be annoying, the grammar doesn't imply it the same way "always" would, like in this example:

> He files a complaint every week or so, but he's always lying.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that the present continuous tense does not always mean something is 'ongoing', if something *never* happens then it is neither present, nor continuous.

So, you would **not** say "*my sister is never borrowing my clothes*". You could say:

> My sister never borrows my clothes.

There are some occasions when it is idiomatic to use '*be*' with certain verbs in the present-continuous tense *and* negate the statement - for example, instead of saying "*don't worry about me*", you could tell someone "*don't be worrying about me*". Note that, unlike your example, this is not a statement of what *doesn't* happen but rather what you are asking *not* to happen.

Further, I wouldn't agree that 'always' and 'continuously' are "often negative" - That would depend entirely on the context. For example, you could say "*my sister is always helping me*", and that would be quite nice, wouldn't it?

Comment: -1 The fact that continuous is used has nothing to do with whether the event itself is continuous. Future plans aren't continuous, and neither is my sister borrowing my clothes. To indicate that something happens on a regular basis without any other nuance, we use *present simple*: *My sister **borrows** my clothes.*" To indicate a such a regular event (not a constant one) with the nuance of annoyance, we use "always" + *present continuous*. It's also possible to use "never" with continuous forms.

Comment: @gotube that wasn't the point at all. I didn't say that we can't use the continuous tense if something isn't continuing... just that, in this case, it **never** happens. I was appealing to the OP to use logic and see why the present continuous tense could not be used.

Comment: Your logic still doesn't flow. If something that never happens isn't present, then why does the correct sentence with "never" have the present simple tense? I'm sure you're familiar with the function of *[ "always" + present continuous ]* to express annoyance at something that *happens* regularly. This question is only about whether *[ "never" + present continuous ]* has that same function. It does not.

Comment: @gotube The 'present simple' is also the **present indefinite**. It isn't just about events, but conditions that exist. When you negate it, the condition doesn't exist. It's that simple. We don't use present continuous for these kinds of statements, but I think you know that and are just doubling down on this minutiae detail to avoid admitting that, ultimately, the answer is correct.